# Out of Memory error when using AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, animation

Hi I'm trying to create a logo animation from a few png images i have created an animation and it crashes with an out of memory error. Does anyone know a solution to this?

heres what i have so far

heres my animation list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_00" android:duration="50" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_01" android:duration="50" />  
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_02" android:duration="50" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_03" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_04" android:duration="50" />  
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_05" android:duration="50" />  
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_06" android:duration="50" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_07" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_08" android:duration="50" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_09" android:duration="50" />  
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_10" android:duration="50" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_11" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_12" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_13" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_14" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_15" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_16" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_17" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_18" android:duration="50" />  
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_19" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_20" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_21" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_22" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_23" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_24" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_25" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_26" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_27" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_28" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_29" android:duration="50" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/intro_animation_30" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

heres my Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myanimation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@anim/intro_animation"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Heres my Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_menu);
        ImageView myAnimation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myanimation);
        final AnimationDrawable myAnimationDrawable
        = (AnimationDrawable)myAnimation.getDrawable();

        myAnimation.post(
        new Runnable(){

          @Override
          public void run() {
           myAnimationDrawable.start();
          }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Increase your heap memory size in emulator..

Comment: i'm using a device not an emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add `largeHeap=true` in your application tag of your
manifest.

I hope this help.

or try using small size image.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Almost felt too easy... just read that impact of this approach is increased time spent on garbage collection and possibility that other apps may have memory issues (on resume of the respective apps, I presume)

Comment: its a temporary solution