# Android ViewPager with Fragment holding ImageView

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, picasso

I have a ViewPager which displays the details of a news entry. You can swipe between the 30 entries back and forth. Each of these entries is a View which holds a ImageView. This ImageView is filled with an image from an URL using Picasso Image Library.

It works fine, but sometimes when I swipe through almost all of the various items (fragments) my app suddenly crashes, getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2208)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.app.mobil.fragment.placeholder.FanpicPlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(FanpicPlaceholderFragment.java:92)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And during swiping I sometimes get following Logcat message (when the current View contains large images loaded into the ImageView):

```
09-25 13:19:59.816  31859-32208/com.app.mobile E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 3276816-byte allocation.
```

I have one concern about the whole thing: The images I load with Picasso into the ImageViews is sometimes quite large (~ 3MB per image).

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using for your ViewPager?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256097/out-of-memory-error-when-using-animationdrawable/22256342#22256342

Comment: Please change using image loader lib may be  effect somting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

in your manifest , in application tag

Comment: Thanks for providing the simplest solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Transform images into layouts to reduce memory size using following code -

**Picasso.with(context).load(url).resize(width, height).into(imageView)**

Make sure that you are using Picasso library with version - *2.3.4*

Comment: I upgraded from 2.3.2 to 2.3.4. Still the same error. That is how I load my images:
Picasso
 .with(context)
 .load(url)
 .resize(1024, 800)
 .centerCrop()
 .into(fanpicImageView);

Comment: Try with reducing image width and height. For example width = 100 and height=50. (1024,800) seems to be very high and it will consume more memory which leads to out of memory error. Try with some minimum values as per your requirement.